# send one document at a time based on condition from multiple documents template in DocuSign using REST API call

Tags: docusignapi

My DocuSign Templates having 2 PDF documents.
Based on condition say Domestic/Offshore, want to send respective document from template via REST API call. Any help or ideas are appreciated.

Also need help to get recipient tabs w.r.t document id from template.

What i'am doing is building separate request body for Domestic and Offshore documents for embedded Signing.

url = baseURL + "/envelopes";

```
            //************* MultiPart Form data ****************
            request = initializeRequest(url, "POST", null, userName, password, integratorKey);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(subscriberInfo.SubscriberAddresses.Find(sa => sa.AddressTypeID == (int)Enumerations.AddressType.SubscriberAddress).CountryName))
                mailingCountry = subscriberInfo.SubscriberAddresses.Find(sa => sa.AddressTypeID == (int)Enumerations.AddressType.SubscriberAddress).CountryName;
            if (mailingCountry == "United States")
            {
                emailSubject = emailSubject + domesticDocumentName;
                // construct an outgoing XML formatted request body for domestic investors
                requestBody = BuildDomesticXMLRequestBody();

                // some extra config for this api call
                documentPath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "DocuSignDocs\\" + domesticDocumentName;
                configureMultiPartFormDataRequest(request, requestBody, documentPath, contentType);
            }
            else
            {
                emailSubject = emailSubject + offshoreDocumentName;
                // construct an outgoing XML formatted request body for offshore investors
                requestBody = BuildOffshoreXMLRequestBody();

                // some extra config for this api call
                documentPath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "DocuSignDocs\\" + offshoreDocumentName;
                configureMultiPartFormDataRequest(request, requestBody, documentPath, contentType);
            }

            // read the http response
            response = getResponseBody(request);
```

But here documents are saved in project root folder. Instead I want them to come from templates.(Template with multiple documents).

When I get recipient view through REST API call I receive XML body with all the tabs of both the document.I need to fetch one document at a time. Does any one know how to get this?

Comment: Why do the documents need to come from one template?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no limit on the number of templates in your account you can just create two templates, each one with one document in it, then just reference the needed template at run-time.  You can even create the same template roles and everything in the templates but just use different documents for each.